# Can we compose REST query which first apply some function on item then compare?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, date-time, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a date which is in Indian time zone, my SharePoint Online site is in different time zone. Now I have a rest query which filters the record.

```
SiteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$filter=StartDateTime le datetime'2017-04-04T18:00:00.000Z'
```

My question is,

Is it possible to format REST call equivalent to

```
SiteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$filter=SomeFunctionWhichConvertBeforeComparision(StartDateTime) le datetime'2017-04-04T18:00:00.000Z'
```

I am not getting any workaround. Any kind of suggestion is most welcome.

I have gone through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx#bk_supported). Here I want to apply some custom functions instead of default function. Is it possible?

Comment: why don't you try to convert the value of `StartDateTime` before your rest call and after that you just pass this converted value in your REST filter.